# Yii2 Email How to set sender name

Tags: yii2

i using Mailer to send email, so i have problem about sender name
This is my config

```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'messageConfig' => [
            'charset' => 'UTF-8',
            'from' => ['admin@app.com' => 'App Sender Name'],
        ],
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_MailTransport',
        ],
    ],
```

So it's not work. I goto inbox and only email showed. 
[image]

And i need show as
Example: 
[image]

Answer (score 9):

it's work when i update setFrom() method.
Ex:  $mailer->setFrom(['email@app.com' => 'App Name']). And here is config Yii2 for send by PHP mail and with sender name

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'messageConfig' => [
            'charset' => 'UTF-8',
            'from' => ['admin@app.com' => 'App Sender Name'],
        ],
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_MailTransport',
        ],
    ],
```

and send email

```
   Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setTo('client@email.com')
    ->setFrom(['admin@app.com' => 'App Name'])
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Every component and sub-component in yii2 is configurable by dependency injection, this case is same, eg:

```
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'noreply.yourcompany@gmail.com',
            'password' => '123456',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
        ],
```

Comment: Thank @ThangDT, i not using SMTP. I config for Using PHP mail. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php