# Yii2 Mask Sender Email

Tags: email, yii2, swiftmailer

I used yii2 application by sending email. Everything is fine. All I want to achieve is to mask the email of sender.

For example the sender email was xxx@sample.com with name of xsample. The receiver can only see the sender as xsample  instead of real email.

I tried to change it from:

```
->setFrom(['unknown@sample.com' => 'xsample'])
```

Here is my mailer configuration:

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' =>  'mail.sample.com',
            'username' =>  'xxxsample@sample.com',
            'password' =>  'xxx',
            'port' =>  '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
    ],
```

But it still read the real email from the config of mailer. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't get many emails without a sender address. None actually. What makes you think it should be possible?

Comment: i want to display it as a computer generated email.

Comment: I would try setting the "from" user name to "no-reply" as in `setFrom('no-reply@sample.com')` (not sure why you put in square brackets). If you still have difficulties please edit the question to make it clearer what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: i'd put it on bracket
['unknown@sample.com' => 'xsample']
to display name as xsample

Answer (score 0):

Try add messageConfig in mailer component

```
 'messageConfig'    => [
                'charset' => 'UTF-8',
                'from'    => ['xxx@sample.com' => 'xsample'],
            ],
```

Comment: plz reference topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218286/yii2-email-how-to-set-sender-name